# Why is the flex code for phone number recognition not working in macOs while the same code works fine in ubuntu?

Tags: macos, flex-lexer

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int n;
%}
%%
^[79][0-9]{9} {printf("Valid Phone number.\n");}
.* {printf("Invalid Phone number.\n");}
%%

int yywrap(){}

int main(){
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a flex code to check if entered lexene is a 10 digit number starting with 7 or 9.

When I compile this code on macOS with flex and then the lex.yy.c file with cc or gcc it does not gives the expected outcome as given in ubuntu. Why is this happening and what could be the possible resolve for it to work fine!

Comment: What specifically goes wrong when you run it on macOS?

Comment: I see that you have no rule for the `'\n'` character. Maybe you enter a new line into the input when testing on macOS and you don't do it when testing on Ubuntu?

Comment: I have presses enter in both machines!
Also in mac it does not accepts the string for the regex in first line whereas in linux the code works fine and it prints valid phone number on entering a 10 digit number that starts with 7 or 9.

Comment: I've tested in on Linux and it really seems to work. I don't have macOS to perform a similar test. Could you include your test file and the output on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have macOS to test it but I suspect this may be a problem with white spaces.
You don't seem to have any rule dedicated to them.

MacOS uses different end of line character than Linux (`\r` instead of `\n`) which may be the cause of the difference in behavior.

Maybe try inserting the following rule into your code to ignore all white spaces.

```
[[:space:]]+ {}
```

Or if you still want to print `"Invalid Phone number.\n"` for spaces, ignore only new line characters, like this:

```
[\r\n]+ {}
```